# How to display listbox on MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, menuitem

I have a WPF code like this:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
   <ListBox.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Delete_Click" />
           <MenuItem Header="Replace" Click="MenuItem_Replace_Click">
               <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding ReplaceItem}" />
           </MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Insert" Click="MenuItem_Insert_Click">
               <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding InsertItem}}" />
           </MenuItem>
</ListBox>
```

But this goes like follows:

**When Mouse leave**
[image: When mouse leave]

**When Mouse On**

[image: When Mouse on]

So how should I fix this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the color of text and background is same. Change the text color to black and check it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a listbox on the MenuItem, why don't you try to add menuitems to the existing menuitem (for your case is "Insert" and "Replace")
Let"s see my example.

```
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = "PX1-20T-D-B";
            NameOfYourMenuItem.Items.Add(mi);
            mi.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MenuItemClick);
```

You can also add the eventHandler for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ListBox in the MenuItem or adding sub menu items in code behind, try using DataTemplates. I assume that you have a collection containing your list box items.

```
<MenuItem Header="Replace" Click="MenuItem_Replace_Click" ItemsSource="{Binding ReplaceItemsCollection}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="replaceSubMenuItem_Clicked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Replace" Click="MenuItem_Replace_Click" ItemsSource="{Binding InsertItemsCollection}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="insertSubMenuItem_Clicked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

In your code behind add:

```cs
private void replaceSubMenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender is the MenuItem. Just parse it.
}

private void insertSubMenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```